# SQL Separate | separated values into new columns - Ordered from right to left

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a hierarchy that I have been able to get into the following format (the spreadsheet I got it from is a complete mess):

[image]

I need to take the values from the AllLevels column and create a new table structured with the following column names:

RegionLevel1     RegionLevel2     RegionLevel3     RegionLevel4   CountryCode  FullPath  HierarchyName

Here's the trick - Everything before the first '|' is always Level1 and the value after the last '|' is always Level4. However Look at 'Central' | 'Poland' | PL. That should go as follows

Level1 - Central,  Level2 - Poland, Level3 - NULL, Level4 - PL

I thought I was somewhat close with this, but I wasn't. Can someone help?

Here is the CTE I used to create this from the raw table:

```
    with  child as
        ( 
        select  ParentCode
             ,      countrycode    
             , Cast (countrycode as varchar(100)) as Level
        from    [dbo].[rawCountryHierarchy]
        where   CountryCode IN (SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(LEFT(BillingLocation, CHARINDEX('-', BillingLocation)-1)) FROM FactSales)
        union all 
        select  e.parentcode
             ,            e.countrycode
             ,            cast (cast(e.countrycode as varchar(100))+' | '+level as varchar(100)) as level
        from    child m
        join    [dbo].[rawCountryHierarchy] e
        on      m.parentcode= e.countrycode
        )

--insert into [dbo].[DimCountryHierarchy]
select  c.ParentCode, c.CountryCode AS rawCountryCode, cast (cast(c.ParentCode as varchar(100))+' | '+level as varchar(100)) as AllLevels, CASE WHEN Level like '%|%' THEN trim(right(level, charindex('|', reverse(level))-1)) END AS CountryCode, r.HierarchyName
from    child c  
inner join rawRegion on c.parentcode = rawRegion.RegionCode
left join rawCountryHierarchy r on  CASE WHEN Level like '%|%' THEN trim(right(level, charindex('|', reverse(level))-1)) END = r.CountryCode
order by AllLevels
option  (maxrecursion 0)
```

Here is where I get the country code from:

```
WHERE CountryCode IN (SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(LEFT(BillingLocation, CHARINDEX('-', BillingLocation)-1)) FROM FactSales)
```

So that actually represents the lowest level.

EDIT:
The columns in the new table I am trying to populate are as follows:

RegionLevel1  RegionLevel2  RegionLevel3  RegionLevel4  CountryCode FullPath  HierarchyName

RegionLevel1 is ALWAYS the first value in the AllLevels column in the picture. CountryCode is ALWAYS the last value after the last '|' in the All Levels column. In between the First and last value in the AllLevels column, the RegionLevel2, RegionLevel3 and RegionLevel4 columns would populate from left to right (i.e. in the case of the first row it would look like: RegionLevel1-Africa, RegionLevel2-Export, RegionLevel3-WestAfrica, RegionLevel4-NULL, CountryCode-NG), then the AllLevels column populates the FullPath and the HierarchyName populates the same column in the new table.

Comment: can you share with us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried to join this to a raw table that I have, but the table is so unorganized that I can’t. Would it help if I gave you the recursive CTE that I wrote to create this table?

Comment: I would say probably. Anything you have tried so far could help us both understand everything you need to do and what are the solutions that do not work for you

Comment: I will do that. It’s possibly that I could just create what I need with the CTE. You might see how, I don’t.

Comment: @Sirmyself it's too long to post as a comment. I just edited my post with the code I used.

Comment: SQL Server version? And please post copy-paste friendly data for all possible cases.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are trying to resolve does not look solvable to me. Sometimes data is too dirty, and this may be the case here.  How would you ever know the difference between Level1 - Central, Level2 - Poland, Level3 - NULL, Level4 - PL  AND Level1 - Central, Level2 - Poland, Level3 - PL
The problem is that the data did not come in with the correct delimiters for levels 3 and 4.
If this came in as Central|Poland||PL (for level 4) OR Central|Poland|PL (for level 3) then this would be solvable, but with this data you presented there is no way to accurately know levels 3 and 4 that I can see.

Comment: Level 3 is always the country code, in other words, the value after the last '|' is always Level 4 and the very first value is always level 1. Level 3 is the one that is tricky.

Answer (score 0):

This method uses [`DelimitedSplit8K`](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) to split your values, and then Pivot them. It might be a bit overkill, but it's a different option which might be worth trying:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.AllLevels (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), --I ASSUME you have an ID column
                            Levels varchar(8000));
INSERT INTO dbo.AllLevels (Levels)
VALUES ('Africa | Export | West Africa | NG'),
       ('Austria | ATALL | AT'),
       ('Central | HU');

GO

WITH Split AS(
    SELECT AL.ID, AL.Levels,
           LTRIM(RTRIM(DS.Item)) AS [Level],
           DS.ItemNumber AS LevelNumber,
           MAX(DS.ItemNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS MaxLevel
    FROM dbo.AllLevels AL
         CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(AL.Levels,'|') DS),
Pivots AS(
    SELECT ID,
           MAX(CASE WHEN LevelNumber = 1 AND LevelNumber < MaxLevel THEN [Level] END) AS Level1,
           MAX(CASE WHEN LevelNumber = 2 AND LevelNumber < MaxLevel THEN [Level] END) AS Level2,
           MAX(CASE WHEN LevelNumber = 3 AND LevelNumber < MaxLevel THEN [Level] END) AS Level3,
           MAX(CASE WHEN LevelNumber = 4 OR LevelNumber = MaxLevel THEN [Level] END) AS Level4
    FROM Split
    GROUP BY ID)
SELECT *
FROM Pivots P
     JOIN dbo.AllLevels AL ON P.ID = AL.ID;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.AllLevels;
```